# Azure AD application object - difference requiredressourceaccess and oauth2permissions

Tags: azure-active-directory

what´s the difference between requiredressource access and the oauth2permissions which i can see in the manifest json file?

I understand, if i add permissions on the app registration these are added as IDs to requiredressourceaccess. If an user consents to the app, these are the scopes/roles which are granted.

i also see oauth2permissions - like user_impersonation which is also needed as scope by the app. 
When does this come in to play?

BR
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requiredResourceAccess` lists the delegated and app permissions that the app requires on other APIs.

`oauth2Permissions` lists the delegated permissions offered by the app.
So if you were building an API, you could specify the delegated permissions usable by other apps there.
Then another app can require access with those permissions.